# segmentation fault from strtok

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strtok

im trying a simple program that will read a string, a capital letter, and 2 floats from input.

no matter how much i debug, change, or check the code or input, i keep getting segmentation fault at the last token read.

the input i enter is: `text A,1,2`. i would like the program to ignore all white spaces and commas between the capital letter and values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

   char *value, *string;
    char buffer[100];
    float x;
    if(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin)==NULL)
                printf("empty input\n");

    string = strtok(buffer, " ");

    if(strcmp(string, "text")==0){  
            if((value = strtok(NULL, " \t\n")!=NULL))  /*seg.falt causes here*/
                sscanf(value, " %f", &x);              /*or here*/
    }
}
```

if i print the value of `value` in the console with `p value` it says `0x1 <error: cannot access memory at adress 0x1` and i assume its a null pointer, but why though? the token should have `2` in it.
any insights on what am i missing?

Comment: strtok is not going to return floats (%f format string)

Comment: ahh my bad, changed it to be:
sscanf(token, "%f", &y);
printf("%f\n",y);

but still i see that x doesnt get the right value (1) from the sscanf. shouldt sscanf get a float from the char-string token and assign it to x?

Comment: You have `int x, y` so try using `"%d"` in `sscanf` and in `printf`, or changing to `float x, y`.

Comment: also I can't reproduce the seg. fault, please try to pin point the problem with a [MRE]

Comment: @ackdary i think this is the best i can shorten the code down to the core problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling your program with a recent GCC produces this warning:

```
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:15:23: warning: assignment to ‘char *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   15 |             if((value = strtok(NULL, " \t\n")!=NULL))  /*seg.falt causes here*/
      |                       ^
```

There is a high chance that fixing the parenthesis to do what you *wanted* them to do will fix the crash:

```
if ((value = strtok(NULL, " \t\n")) != NULL)
```

P.S. You should get into a habit of building your programs with `gcc -Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: welp, you beat me to it.
also, i am using Wall flag, but what Wextra does?

Comment: @EricParker Use the power of internet: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Answer (score -1):

found the problem, and its annoying as it can get:

```
if((value = strtok(NULL, " \t\n")!=NULL))
                                        ^
```

should be :

```
if((value = strtok(NULL, " \t\n"))!=NULL)
                                 ^
```